# Error propagation to a parameter due to uncertainty in other parameters

Tags: error-propagation

I have a function $y = f(x,a,b,c)$ where $a$,$b$,$c$ are parameters. I'm given this curve and I'm trying to extract the value of $a$ given I know $b$ and $c$. However, I have some uncertainty in $b$ and $c$ (call it $\delta b$ and $\delta c$), and I'm trying to find the uncertainty in $a$ as a result.

The error propagation formula is:

$\delta a = \sqrt{(\frac{\partial a}{\partial b}\delta b)^2+(\frac{\partial a}{\partial c}\delta c)^2}$

However, this calculates the error propogated to $a$ at a single point $(x_0,y_0)$. Clearly in practice the error propogated to $a$ would be less if you accounted for the whole curve. How would I account for this though, and what is the final value of $\delta a$?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The question is not very clear. I assume $y = f(x,a,b,c) + \text{noise}$, where the noise has some distribution? Perhaps a Bayesian formulation of this problem would be suitable: put a prior distribution over your parameters $a$, $b$, and $c$ and follow the Bayesian approach of deriving a posterior distribution.

Comment: Hey sorry for not being so clear. There is no noise in the graph $y$ vs $x$. Instead there is only uncertainty in the parameters $b$ and $c$. This will be more clear in an example.

Say I have a formula for a line $y = a b c^2 x$, and let's say I've measured the parameters $b=1\pm 0.1$ and $c=3 \pm 0.1$. Now let's say I'm given 'perfect' data for the curve which makes the curve $y = 18x$. Now I want to work out what the value of $a$ is:

Well, clearly $a=2$ but what is the uncertainty in $a$?

I hope that makes things clearer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, since you assume no noise on the curve, there will be no additional information on $(a,b)$ from additional observations of $(x,y)$, since all information is already captured in the first observation. You could say that, even with data $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ , $(y_1, \dots, y_n)$, just the observation $(x_1, y_1)$ is a sufficient statistic for this model. You can see it in your example: $abc^2 = y_1/x_1$ gives a condition on $a b c^2$ given a single observation and more data will not help to gain further information. In practice if $y$ is a measurement value it makes more sense that there is some noise and then again a Bayesian approach might be suitable to understand the posterior uncertainty in $a$ conditional on the data and a suitable prior on $b$ and $c$.